# How to obtain user specific data with FourSquare using Python (with authentication)

Tags: python, api, foursquare

I'm trying to  query the FourSquare API to obtain user-specific information and venue centric information . I've been successfully able to get the venue centric data , however I'm clueless  about the user centric information . I tried following [this link](http://pkarl.com/articles/connect-foursquare-api-oauth-python/).
However the request_token url returns nothing . :(.
It would be great if someone could point out .
1) Where I'm possibly going wrong .
2) Also , suggest the right approach if my approach is completely wrong.

EDIT - Here's some of the modified code from the snippet

```
     <!-- language: python -->
                     ### GET A REQUEST TOKEN ###

consumer=oauth.Consumer(key="NN3TBSPRBCVJMWCDPN1WELO1LOQLXAA31Q40WHW2L1BI5L1X", secret="RVMP1GUQCMFLX31ME5DJKKMZDZFBNYYVV5BKGVXZNWN2MDVM")

request_token_url = 'http://foursquare.com/oauth/request_token'

client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print 'Request tokens are',request_token.keys()
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])


### CREATE A SIGNED CONSUMER REQUEST ###

# Set the API endpoint 
url = "http://api.foursquare.com/v1/authexchange"

# Set the base oauth_* parameters along with any other parameters required
# for the API call.
params = {
'oauth_version': "1.0",
'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
'fs_username': 'MyFourSquare Username',
'fs_password': 'MyFourSquarePassword',
'oauth_token': request_token['oauth_token'],
'oauth_consumer_key': consumer.key,
}

req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)

# Sign the request.
signature_method = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)


### Make the auth request ###

test = 'http://api.foursquare.com/v1/test.json'

resp, content = client.request(test, "GET")

print resp
print content # prints 'ok'
```

I get the following error when I run the code .

```
Request tokens are []
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testingFour.py", line 60, in <module>
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
KeyError: 'oauth_token'
```

From what I can make out the request tokens are being  returned empty, any idea why this could be happening?

-----------------------------------SECOND--EDIT: --------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is the error I get when I try to print resp,content. I know that I'm calling the wrong url , but clearly substituting ouath2 for oauth isn't helping

```
 {'status': '400', 'content-length': '91', 'expires': 'Thu, 15 Sep 2011 12:04:57 UTC', 'server': 'nginx/0.8.52', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, private, no-store', 'date': 'Thu, 15 Sep 2011 12:04:57 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'} AS PART OF THE APIV1 SUNSET, OAUTH V1 HAS BEEN DIABLED. SEE HTTP://DEVELOPER.FOURSQUARE.COM
Request tokens are []
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testingFour.py", line 60, in <module>
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
KeyError: 'oauth_token'
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It would be useful If you could provide some code to show how you modified the source from the given link.

Comment: @rocksportrocker, sure have a look above!

Comment: I would print the results from calling client.request.

Comment: It doesn't reach there. It  stops at the oauth_token part giving a key error .   The URL  returns nothing .

Comment: @rocksportrocker, yep that^pretty much is the problem!

Comment: @crazyaboutliv resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET") should be reached, line 60 is much below

Comment: @rocksportrocker,It does not reach the line -resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

Comment: @KodeSeeker but your error in your message is below this line. Is your code fragment up to date ?

Comment: @rocksportrocker, I've updated my post with an edit , to provide a better idea.

Comment: So the dict request_token is empty (that is what "Request tokens are []" says), and you wonder that retrieving "request_token[xyz]" fails ?

Comment: Not wondering I guess.Just need to know the right way of going about getting data from the foursquare API .

Comment: @rocksportrocker, just miserably stuck atm ^.^

Comment: you should also print 'resp' and 'content'. I guess your request failed for some reasons.

Comment: @rocksportrocker,  yeah the result of printing  resp and content is posted above(specified under the second EDIT) .   OP, can you post the updated code with the extra print for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv,@rocksportrocker, I've made the second edit more visible..

Comment: look at the output: AS PART OF THE APIV1 SUNSET, OAUTH V1 HAS BEEN DIABLED. SEE HTTP://DEVELOPER.FOURSQUARE.COM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As plaes mentioned, foursquare's V1 library is deprecated and shut down.

Docs for foursquare's V2 api are here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

A comprehensive foursquare Python library can be found here: https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare

Pythonic, simple, full unit-testing. *Disclaimer: I wrote the library*

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect to FourSquare **API v1**. But this has been disable by now:

```
AS PART OF THE APIV1 SUNSET, OAUTH V1 HAS BEEN DIABLED. SEE HTTP://DEVELOPER.FOURSQUARE.COM
```

Apparently the example your are using is outdated.